# Correct way to extend Prestashop 1.7

Tags: prestashop

In PS 1.7 documentation, we can read multiple time that the PS override system is not recommended, an it's not allowed to publish module in the PS marketplace.

We have to only use hooks, and extend existing class, and I understood why.

But how to use the extended class instead of the core one in our custom theme ?

Let use a example :

I want to add a custom field for categories.

In a module I extend the CategoryCore class :

```
class Category extend CategoryCore{

     private $bottom_description
     ...
}
```

Then to add the field in the category's admin page I can use some hook like displayBackOfficeCategory and actionBeforeAddCategory.

But I'm not sure for the front : the new variable have to be accessible in some theme templates files.

In my custom theme, in the category.tpl template, $category->bottom_description is undefined.

Fix this issue by overriding the CategoryController  is easy,but how to do this only with hook ?

The only way I found is to use the actionFrontControllerSetMedia hook, like this :

```
function HookActionFrontControllerSetMedia(){
      // get my custom Category object base on url
      this->context->smarty->assign(["category_bottom_description"=>$category->buttom_description]);
   }
```

This look tricky, and my new field is still not accessible in other context.

So what is the proper way to get this property available in my custom them ?

Ideally, the new property should be available every time we found a category object, like this : $category->bottom_description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not forget to define a new field at category class because at the front you have not a class instance but an array which is converted within `ObjectPresenter` class. So follow this way. Extend your `Category` class and add all necessary definitions

```
class Category extends CategoryCore
{
    public $bottom_description;

    public function __construct($idCategory = null, $idLang = null, $idShop = null)
    {
        Category::$definition['fields']['bottom_description'] = array('type' => self::TYPE_HTML, 'lang' => true, 'validate' => 'isCleanHtml');
        $this->bottom_description = 'bottom_description'; // just to add demo data
        parent::__construct($idCategory, $idLang, $idShop);
    }
}
```

and then the field `bottom_description` will be available in the `category.tpl` but like an array {$category.bottom_description}. Hope it will help you.

Comment: I didn't know that, thank ! But it isn't a problem to add field in core table database? (for exemple when updating core) It is not better to create a separated table ? This help in part : how to inject data to theme tpl, if I need it anywhere else hook in some theme tpl ?

Comment: If I've understood everything right I'll try to answer. I think that it is better to use your own table instead of modifying defaults(my own opinion) but exactly in this new class, you can relate your new functionality with the old category's one and later get it in every page where {$category} variable is available. Also, you can add/update/remove it within this class within extending of default class methods add, update, delete. To learn more peep into class ObjectModel which is the base class for Category class. Hope I answered your question.

Comment: Yes, my english need a litle bit more improvement sorry ^^. Ok I'll look into this direction. THank !

Comment: Just to be sure : your exemple is not a override? It's just a extend in a module? 'cause I can't make it work ...

Comment: Basically, it isn't an override but it still has consequences and you still cannot extend a class twice. But in this approach, your module will be allowed to install it through an admin panel. So as a conclusion I would say that there isn't a safe way to do overrides and all of the methods is just are bypasses and it's better to use them only in certain environments. To make your extension work - include your new class file in your module's mian class file this way include_once _PS_MODULE_DIR_ . 'your_module/path_to_php_clas';

Comment: still not working with the include_once in my module main file, except if I put it in the override folder, witch I want to avoide :)